# Dynamic Update Concatenate function for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which is used for concatenation. The cells are dynamic; whenever a change in cells in a range the concatenation function will automatically execute and gives the value. Currently I asked the concatenation function which has to run for the complete range even though the modification is in a single row. Which is causing a lot of time during the execution.

Is there is any way to define to update only a single row that is modified? I know the technique if the range is single column, for multiple columns I didn't have any idea.

*My Code*

```
    ColumnLetter3 = Split(Cells(1, c1_column).Address, "$")(1)
    ColumnLetter4 = Split(Cells(1, c6_column).Address, "$")(1)
    Range3 = ColumnLetter3 & st_workrow2 + 1 & ":" & ColumnLetter4 & last_cell1
    Set xrng3 = Range(Range3)

    If Not Application.Intersect(xrng3, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then

        For i = c_row + 1 To last_cell1
        If Cells(i, c1_column) = "" And Cells(i, c2_column) = "" And Cells(i, c3_column) = "" And Cells(i, c4_column) = "" And Cells(i, c5_column) = "" And Cells(i, c6_column) = "" Then
        Cells(i, c_column) = ""
            Else
            Cells(i, c_column) = Cells(i, c1_column) & "-" & Cells(i, c2_column) & "-" & Cells(i, c3_column) & "-" & Cells(i, c4_column) & "-" & Cells(i, c5_column) & "-" & Cells(i, c6_column)
            Cells(i, c_column).Replace what:="+", Replacement:=""
            Cells(i, c_column).Replace what:="-----", Replacement:="-"
            Cells(i, c_column).Replace what:="----", Replacement:="-"
            Cells(i, c_column).Replace what:="---", Replacement:="-"
            Cells(i, c_column).Replace what:="--", Replacement:="-"
            If Right(Cells(i, c_column), 1) = "-" Then
                l = Len(Cells(i, c_column))
                Cells(i, c_column) = Left(Cells(i, c_column), l - 1)
            End If
            If Left(Cells(i, c_column), 1) = "-" Then
                l = Len(Cells(i, c_column))
                Cells(i, c_column) = Right(Cells(i, c_column), l - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next I
    Endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing here (perhaps strip down your question?), however looks like you want to get a list of the rows in your `target`? In that case you can isolate it using `Columns(1)`. See below...

```
If Not Application.Intersect(xrng3, Range(Target.Address)) _
    Is Nothing Then

    Dim aCell As Range

For Each aCell In Target.Columns(1).Cells
    i = aCell.Row

    If Cells(i, c1_column) = "" And Cells(i, c2_column) = "" And Cells(i, c3_column) = "" And Cells(i, c4_column) = "" And Cells(i, c5_column) = "" And Cells(i, c6_column) = "" Then
        'skipped....
    End If
Next aCell
End If
```

Comment: The intention is as below,